# return json name custom utils nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have utils pagination.js

```
exports.getPagination = function (page, size) {
  const limit = size ? +size : 3;
  const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;

  return { limit, offset };
};

exports.getPagingData = function (datas, page, limit) {
  const { count: total_items, rows: scores } = datas;
  const current_page = page ? +page : 0;
  const total_pages = Math.ceil(total_items / limit);

  return { total_items, scores, total_pages, current_page }; // here problem 
};
```

i have use like these

```
    const { page, size, title } = req.query;
    const { limit, offset } = pagination.getPagination(page, size);
....
....
    .then( async (scores) => {
      const resData = pagination.getPagingData(scores, page, limit);
      // const resData = pagination.getPagingData(scores, page, limit);
      response.ok(res, "load scores data", resData);
```

my json return

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "load scores data",
  "data": {
    "total_items": 4222,
    "scores": [
      {
        "id": 3,
```

how i can naming flexible **`scores`** when i use the utils on other controller ?

for example

```
    .then( async (events) => {
      const resData = pagination.getPagingData(events, page, limit);
      response.ok(res, "load events data", resData);
```

so my json return
expected :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "load events data",
  "data": {
    "total_items": 4222,
    "events": [
      {
        "id": 3,
```

Actual results:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "load events data",
  "data": {
    "total_items": 4222,
    "scores": [ // here problem
      {
        "id": 3,
```

anyone have trick with separate file ? passing value as key ? dynamic key naming.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another argument to your getPagingData function like so:

```
exports.getPagingData = function (datas, page, limit, dynamicKey) {
   const { count: total_items, rows: scores } = datas;
   const current_page = page ? +page : 0;
   const total_pages = Math.ceil(total_items / limit);

   return { total_items, [dynamicKey]: scores, total_pages, current_page }; // here problem 
};
```

then you can call this function

```
const resData = pagination.getPagingData(events, page, limit, "events");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do it to pass the resource name to your `getPagingData` function. Like so:

```
exports.getPagingData = function (datas, page, limit, resourceName) {
  const { count: total_items, rows } = datas;
  const current_page = page ? +page : 0;
  const total_pages = Math.ceil(total_items / limit);
  const result = { total_items, total_pages, current_page };
  /**
   * DO YOUR PAGINATION LOGIC SOMEWHERE HERE
   */
  result[resourceName] = rows;
  return result;
};
```

And when you need to call the function, you call it as shown below:

```
const resource_name = "events"; // or "scores", as the case may be.
const resData = pagination.getPagingData(scores, page, limit, resource_name);
```

Hope this answers your question.